# What are practical use cases for JavaScript Streams

Tags: javascript, stream, bacon.js

I'm been learning how to use JavaScript 'node-style' streams using [Bacon.js](https://baconjs.github.io/). Namely, I've been looking at the [`Bus` `EventStreams`](https://baconjs.github.io/api.html#bus).

It all looks very interesting and I'm sure that JavaScript streams have a multitude of great use cases, but I can't seem to think of a single practical application.

Can anyone provide me with some examples of use cases for Streams?

Comment: What practical use case are you trying to solve? We'll show you how to do it with streams.

Comment: I don't have any specific problems to solve that I feel streams can solve, hence my question

Comment: Not one where *you feel* that streams would solve it, but just some arbitrary specific problem (preferably complex enough to need asynchronous events).

Comment: Gotcha. Perhaps something like a messaging service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used it to handle key events, update values in near real time via Server Side Push/Web socket, and combine with other events to determine a behavior to act upon (ex. if the page has focus when a web socket event fires, update a field..).

Here are a few more...

- Determine if user is active on a page -

  ```
  var blur = $(window).asEventStream('blur').map(function() { return false; });
  var focus = $(window).asEventStream('focus').map(function() { return true; }); 
  var focused = focus.merge(blur).toProperty(true);
  ```

via http://blog.flowdock.com/2013/01/22/functional-reactive-programming-with-bacon-js/

TypeAhead - See movie search example at https://baconjs.github.io/

Registration Form, Shopping Cart - see https://baconjs.github.io/tutorials.html

Handling Web Socket Connections/Events - http://blog.carbonfive.com/2014/09/23/bacon-js-node-js-mongodb-functional-reactive-programming-on-the-server/
and
https://medium.com/@garychambers108/functional-reactive-react-js-b04a8d97a540